# What's wrong with this jQuery statement

Tags: jquery

Basically I have the following

```
$("#amount").keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val() != "") {
        alert($(this).closest("form").find('input[id="price"]').val());
    }
});
```

The **HTML** layout is as follows

```
<form class="submitOrder" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Amount</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
             <label>Price</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" value="$1" disabled="">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

According to this statement, `$(this).val()` always returns an empty value meaning the `alert` won't be processed, why is this?

My exact **HTML** mockup within a JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/7PPBq/3/

Comment: You left out the element that your function is referring to. Post the HTML as well.

Comment: is #amount an input value?

Comment: What is `#amount` a text box? Show the HTML you are attempting to interact with. It will make answering your question easier. Even better create a jsfiddle demonstrating your problem.

Comment: can you share the relevant html also

Comment: I've gone ahead and added the **HTML**, sorry for forgetting to that add guys

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CrWhn/1/ is your code written inside a dom ready handler

Comment: like in http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CrWhn/2/

Comment: Is there any other jQuery code in your page thats causing issues? check your console for erroors. the code youce posted is fine

Comment: In my conosole I'm receiving no problems, here's my exact HTML mockup : http://jsfiddle.net/7PPBq/3/

Comment: You should get in the habit of using `console.log()`. Why? For one you don't get some annoying popup and most importantly, if you log an object you can inspect it in the console.

Comment: You have multiple inputs with id of "amount".  There should only be 1 unique id per page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 problems:

1. You have multiple uses of the same id for both 'price' and 'amount'.  Ids need to be unique.  You may want to give the inputs a name attribute instead of or in addition to the id, since the name will be how the input is identified in a post.
2. The html was invalid.  There are divs in the form that don't end where they should.

[See this fiddler for a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/7PPBq/3/)

```
 <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-7">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
                <li class="active"><a href="#facebook" data-toggle="tab">Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="#twitter" data-toggle="tab">Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href="#youtube" data-toggle="tab">YouTube</a></li>
                <li><a href="#instagram" data-toggle="tab">Instagram</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="ajaxResponse"></div>
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="facebook">
                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Create Order</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <form class="submitOrder" method="POST">
                                <fieldset>
                                        <label for="fname">Amount</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount">

                                        <label for="fname">Price</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" value="$1" disabled>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--/span-->
    </div><!--/row-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot have more than one element that share the exact same ID**

Change all `id="amount"` to `class="amount"`.

Change all `id="price"` to `class="price"`.

Change your JS to:

```
$(".amount").keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val() != "") {
        alert($(this).closest("form").find(".price").val());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any problem here. Have you imported the jQuery library?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery191.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/whyach/LDYxD/

Comment: If jQuery wasn't imported, there would be a console error, which is opposite of what OP stated.

Comment: OP said nothing from console. Why you assume there's no error from the console?

Comment: anyway, this should have been posted as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Well,when I posted this answer,there's no comment about console yet. And based on the code provided by OP, this is the most possible reason I can think of. Of course now not valid since OP added comment and his own JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
$("#amount").keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val() != "") {
        alert($(this).parents('.tab-pane').find('input[id="price"]').val());
    }
});
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7PPBq/4/)